# How to classify univariate time series data in real-time?

Tags: time-series, classification, univariate

I have a robotic arm doing three different tasks, each task is colored differently as seen below. Data correspond to a **Z-axis** of the gyroscope sensor.
[image: 3 signals]

The idea is to detect anomalies. However, I need to know where the anomaly occurred as well, so I need to keep track of the tasks. I believe spotting the starting point of each task would ease this process. So, I am trying to **determine the ongoing task** solely based on the **Z-axis of the gyroscope sensor.**

Edit: There is no guarantee that the tasks will be in the same order.

Edit 2: The detection should be done as soon as possible. The graph shows an angular velocity. The earlier we recognize the new phase is better, there is no specific time limit.

Comment: You need to further clarify your question, and especially to provide details on 1) which information you have access to and 2) what you wish to obtain. I understand that you have access only to the measurements of the gyroscope sensor, and that you are trying to determine in which task you are (blue, red, or green). Is that correct?

Comment: Hi @CamilleGontier. Yes, exactly. 1) I only have access to Z-axis of the gyroscope, 2) Indeed, I am trying to determine the ongoing tasks. There are 3 tasks where each color represents a different task.

Comment: Is 'in real-time' an essential part to the question, as in: more than just related to how you program it? For example do you want a detection before the robot arm has finished the entire task? Or do you want the algorithm to keep updating itselve based on new information?

Comment: The question is a bit broad. Classifying time signals is a very broad topic and there are various approaches depending on the properties of the signal and what you know about it (There's even an entire seperate website about it https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signal-detection). It seems difficult to cover all that in a single q&a. Could you explain more about your signals.

Comment: Is the graph for the rotational position, rotational speed or rotational acceleration?

Comment: The graph has phase transitions marked at times 2600 and 2800. How soon after those phase transitions does the algorithm need to recognize the new phase? Eg recognizing the new phase after 100 units of time is probably easy, and recognizing it after 10 units of time is probably impossible with just the graph data.

Comment: Hi @SextusEmpiricus, please check the edited question.

Comment: Hi @MattF, the earlier is better, I edited the question.

Comment: A problem like this should be tackled by *first* listing the domain knowledge that is available for this problem. What sort of tasks for the robot arm are we taking about? Can we already make some theoretic assumptions about the way that the signals will look like and vary. If there are anomalies how are we supposed to train the model to detect them? Should the algorithm work in different situations (sensor wrongly attached, different scale of robot arm, etc)? The answering of these type of questions should *precede* any thoughts about what sort of statistical analysis to use.

Answer (score 1):

Given your plot and your input, I will assume that your 3 tasks are mostly characterized by different amplitudes and variability of the signal: moderate for blue, high for red, low for green. There are different implementations you could try, of increasing complexity and robustness/generability:

1. A first ad hoc and intuitive solution is to detect peaks in your signal (e.g. by detecting sign changes in its time derivative), and to compare the amplitude of the peaks to an hard-coded threshold (moderate for blue, high for red, low for green). A bit hacky, you would need to play around with the values of these thresholds and the method to detect peaks.
2. A different approach is to compute the variance of your recordings on a sliding window, and compare it to a threshold. A each time step $t$, use data points from $t-N$ to $t$ to compute the variance and classify your signal accordingly. Different values for the width of the time window $N$ will give you different results.
3. Finally, a fancier way is to fit a [Hidden Markov Model (HMM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model) on previous data, where the observation $y$ corresponds to the output of the gyroscope and the hidden state $x$ corresponds to the task. You can find a great deal of literature on how to perform HMM fitting and filtering on this website or anywhere online.

I would advise to start with the simpler solution, and to move forwards to test for better results.

Comment: Variance over a sliding window looks like the simplest of these options — classifying based on peaks based on changes of direction seems complicated and unreliable.

Comment: @MattF., is 1st approach less complex (cost less) than the 2nd? I will run this on an embedded board, so would prefer the most simple option.